# Get reports from power bi api

Tags: rest, powerbi, postman

I want to get reports of my power bi by api

I do this steps:

- Create new app and grant permisions
  [image]
- Create new certificate
  [image]
- Add the redirect url
  [image]
- Get token: Doing the call from postman WITH Directory (tenant) ID (otherwise get 404) and get token
  [image]
- When put the token and call {{pbi-base-url}}/groups/:group_id/reports get 401:
  [image]

I can't use user-password normal call because have two factor authentication for users

- In workspaces i see this
  [image]
  What am I doing wrong? Am I missing a step?

Thx

In details of problem

Comment: Did you acquired an access token first and how? It is not in the steps shown.

Comment: Is the screenshot after "Doing the call from postman WITH Directory (tenant) ID (otherwise get 404) and get token"

Comment: Is this application member of the workspace, for which you are trying to get the reports? This is required when using [Get Report In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/get-report-in-group), otherwise you must call an admin API, like [GetReportsInGroupAsAdmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/reports-get-reports-in-group-as-admin), but in this case the app must not have any admin-consent required permissions for Power BI.

Comment: "Is this application member of the workspace, for which you are trying to get the reports? This is required when using Get Report In Group"... How i can check and do it? I only see "In workspaces i see this" from post